# Workaround for problems with "!" literals in a For loop with delayed variable expansion

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

How do I make a workaround for the FOR Loop? The problem is that DelayedExpansion fails for filenames with "!" in them

The code (this is part of a bigger script)

```
:FileScan
::Sets the filenames(in alphabetical order) to variables
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "EpCount=0"
FOR /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x IN ('Dir /b /o:n %~dp0*.mkv* *.mp4* *.avi* *.flv* 2^>nul') DO (
    SET /a "EpCount+=1"
    SET Ep!EpCount!=%%x
)
IF %EpCount%==0 ( Echo. & Echo: No Episodes Found & GOTO :Err )

:FolderScan
::Sets the foldernames(in alphabetical order) to variables
SET "FolderCount=0"
FOR /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x IN ('Dir /b /o:n /a:d "%~dp0Put_Your_Files_Here" 2^>nul') DO (
    SET /a "FolderCount+=1"
    SET Folder!FolderCount!=%%x
)
```

If not possible in batch how do I do it in PowerShell 
to something that can be called by the original batch like:

```
:FileScan
Call %~dp0FileScanScript.ps1
IF %EpCount%==0 ( Echo. & Echo: No Episodes Found & GOTO :Err )
:FolderScan
Call %~dp0FolderScanScript.ps1
```

EDIT: CALL SET fixed the original code avoiding DelayedExpansion altogether

```
SET "EpCount=0"
FOR /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x IN ('Dir /b /o:n %~dp0*.mkv* *.mp4* *.avi* *.flv* 2^>nul') DO (
    SET /a "EpCount+=1"
    CALL SET "Ep%%EpCount%%=%%x"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is indeed to use [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)`set` to introduce another parsing phase:

```cmd
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0."
set /A "EpCount=0"
for /F "delims=" %%x in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /O:N "*.mkv*" "*.mp4*" "*.avi*" "*.flv*" 2^> nul
') do (
    set /A "EpCount+=1"
    call set "Ep%%EpCount%%=%%x"
)
popd
endlocal
```

However, this causes problems as soon as carets `^` appear in the strings or file names, because `call` doubles them when they appear quoted.

To solve this, you need to make sure that the strings are expanded in the second parsing phase too, which can be achieved by using an interim variable, like this:

```cmd
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0."
set /A "EpCount=0"
for /F "delims=" %%x in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /O:N "*.mkv*" "*.mp4*" "*.avi*" "*.flv*" 2^> nul
') do (
    set "Episode=%%x"
    set /A "EpCount+=1"
    call set "Ep%%EpCount%%=%%Episode%%"
)
popd
set Ep
endlocal
```

In addition, I added the filter option `/A:-D` to [`dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to ensure that no directories are returned. Furthermore, I used [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) to change to the parent directory of the script temporarily. The `dir` command line as you wrote it, searched files `*.mkv*` in the parent directory of the script, but all the other ones in the current working directory, which is probably not what you wanted.

---

Another option is to toggle delayed expansion, so that the `for` variable reference `%%x` becomes expanded when delayed expansion is disabled, and the assignment to the `Ep` array-style variables is done when it is enabled. But you need to implement measures to transport variable values beyond the `endlocal` barrier then, like in the following example:

```cmd
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0."
set /A "EpCount=0"
for /F "delims=" %%x in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /O:N "*.mkv*" "*.mp4*" "*.avi*" "*.flv*" 2^> nul
') do (
    rem /* Delayed expansion is disabled at this point, so expanding
    rem    the `for` variable reference `%%x` is safe here: */
    set "Episode=%%x"
    set /A "EpCount+=1"
    rem // Enable delayed expansion here:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Use a `for /F` loop that iterates once only over the assignment string,
    rem    which cannot be empty, so the loop always iterates; the expanded value
    rem    is stored in `%%z`, which must be assigned after `endlocal` in order
    rem    to have it available afterwards and not to lose exclamation marks: */
    for /F "delims=" %%z in ("Ep!EpCount!=!Episode!") do (
        endlocal
        set "%%z"
    )
)
popd
set "Ep"
endlocal
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the directory problem, also while testing I found that it seems not just `^` but also `%` are problematic, does this also work for `%` in filenames?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, both solutions work with `%` signs; you just have to take care that you double the `%` when you specify strings directly: to assign the string `String with a % sign` to a variable, you need to state `set "STRING=String with a %% sign"` in a batch file...

Answer (score 1):

```
CALL SET Ep%%EpCount%%=%%x
```

would set your variables appropriately, as would

```
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%x IN (
 'Dir /b /o:n %~dp0*.mkv* *.mp4* *.avi* *.flv* 2^>nul ^|find /v /n ""'
 ) DO (
 SET /a epcount=%%x
 CALL SET ep%%x=%%y
)
```

(prefix each name with `[num]` then use `for` to extract `num` to `%%x` and `name` to `%%y` (assuming there are no names that start `[` or `]`))

Comment: wow this works way better but is there no way to avoid "[" and "]" as delims cause some files I encounter have these

Comment: Well, only by using `findstr`, but that would mean replacing `delims` with `:`. However, the `tokens=1*` means that only the `[]` surrounding the number will be affected. The`dir` output line would be `[36]some [name] including []`; `%%x` would acquire the `36` and `%%y` **everything** after the first sequence of delimiters (leading delimiters are ignored) hence `%%y` would acquire `some [name] including []` - just so long as it doesn't *start* with `[` or `]`. Anywhere other than the first character will be safe.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Note: The OP had originally tagged the question [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) in addition to [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), but later removed that tag (since restored).</sup>

The equivalent of the following batch-file (`cmd`) loop:

```cmd
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x IN ('Dir /b /o:n %~dp0*.mkv* *.mp4* *.avi* *.flv* 2^>nul') DO (
    SET /a "EpCount+=1"
    SET Ep!EpCount!=%%x
)
```

in **PowerShell** (PSv3+) is:

```powershell
# Collect all episode paths in array $Eps
$Eps = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $PSScriptRoot -Include *.mkv, *.mp4, *.avi, *.flv).FullName
# Count the number of paths collected.
$EpCount = $Eps.Count
```

The above will work with paths that have embedded `!` instances too.
`$Eps` will be an *array* of the full filenames.

---

To then **process the matching files one by one**:

```powershell
foreach ($ep in $Eps) { # Loop over all files (episodes)
  # Work with $ep
}
```

Using a single *array* rather than distinct `$Ep1`, `$Ep2`, ... variables makes for much simpler and more efficient processing.

---

The above is the fastest way to process the already-collected-in-memory filenames one by one.
A **more memory-efficient (though slightly slower), pipeline-based approach** would be:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $PSScriptRoot -Include *.mkv,*.mp4,*.avi,*.flv | ForEach-Object {
  # Work with $_.FullName - automatic variable $_ represents the input object at hand.
}
```